# Cast to type which is not single-word

Tags: c++, casting

C-style and function-style casts are discouraged. For single-word types there is a nice form `byte{33}`. But what about other types? I know I can write (since C++20; before that it'd require defining a template class myself) `type_identity_t<signed char>{33}`. Can it be simplified?

I've tried (signed char){33} which compilers also accept. What is it? A C-style cast of `initializer_list`, perhaps?

Comment: Also (not part of the question to avoid closure because it could be considered asking for software recommendation), are there any nice online tools which can parse C++ code and display a syntax tree? I could probably very easily answer this question myself, had I found one (I haven't on my own and Google Bard gives false leads).

Comment: You can always make and use a typedef.

Comment: One option: `using signed_char = signed char; signed_char{33};`

Comment: (Note that since the question is concerned about a solution for older C++ versions, it may be better to make a type alias with the `typedef` keyword not the `using` keyword)

Comment: @BenVoigt, @Eljay, I've upvoted your comments; I thought about that too, but I don't find it simpler than using `type_identity`. And no, @BenVoight, there mention of older versions is only parenthetical; I'd accept an answer requiring C++20.

Comment: Why not `static_cast`?